# What is the easiest way to hide rows that already appear in a table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, row

What I mean is I have 2 tables, one is a table of list of courses (`courses`) and the second is a table of listed courses I am registered in(`StudentCourseRegistration`). I want to know how to emit the primary keys I saved in the `StudentCourseRegistration` table, called `CourseCode`, to hide from the `course` table **when i call to display this table**

So if row data "CourseCode" -> CAD9047 appears in the `registered` table, then do not show it when I call the `courses` table. Of course, I cannot hard code the exact course code I want to emit from that table so it's dynamically changing once that code has been registered with that user.

Is a query the best way to do it?

Here is where I cam calling the output table:

```
$string2012 = "SELECT Course.CourseCode, Course.Title, Course.WeeklyHours, Semester.Term, Semester.SemesterCode
    FROM Course, CourseOffer, Semester, StudentCourseRegistration WHERE Semester.YearNum='$selectedYear' AND Course.CourseCode=CourseOffer.CourseCode 
    AND Semester.SemesterCode=CourseOffer.SemesterCode ";
    if($Result2012 = mysqli_query($link, $string2012))
    {
        echo "<form action='CourseSelection.php' method='get'>
        <table><tr><th>Code</th><th>Course Title</th><th>Hours</th><th>Term</th><th>Select</th></tr>";
        while($row2012 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result2012))
        {
            echo "<tr><td>$row2012[CourseCode]</td><td>$row2012[Title]</td><td>$row2012[WeeklyHours]</td>
            <td>$row2012[Term]</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='courses[]' value='$row2012[CourseCode]'></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
```

**Can I specify primary/foreign keys in one table to now show in another if they exist?**

Comment: Personally, I would avoid comma separated lists of tables in a `FROM` clause, favouring explicit specification of the type of join. I.e. instead of `...FROM course, courseoffer...` use `...FROM course INNER JOIN courseoffer ON course.coursecode = courseoffer.coursecode`. It is easier to make mistakes using cross joins as you are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM course c
WHERE c.coursecode 
    NOT IN(SELECT r.coursecode FROM studentcourseregistration r)
```

If you do this a lot you might want to:

```
CREATE VIEW filtered_courses AS
    SELECT *
    FROM course c
    WHERE c.coursecode 
        NOT IN(SELECT r.coursecode FROM studentcourseregistration r)
```